# Visual studio code with SDL2 problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl-2

I am trying to get SDL2 working with visual studio code and it seems like it can't find the header files.

This is the error I get in the Terminal.

```
Executing task: C:/MinGW/bin/g++ C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\bin C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\lib <
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\bin: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\codyc\Desktop\SDL\SDL2-2.0.8\i686-w64-mingw32\lib: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing a open source library like SDL2 for windows development and doing cross-compiling with tools like mingw32 could be quite challenging for starters.

It is recommended to download vcpkg, which is a open source packager for visual studio C++, from GitHub. Once installed, you can import many such projects through Powershell command line. In your case it will look something like this : `.\vcpjg install sdl2:x64-windows-static`